# Google Analytics AJAX e-commerce tracking

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, google-analytics, e-commerce

Say I have an index.html which initiates the Universal Google Analytics tracking code:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Later I load an HTML document which I insert via AJAX. Can I put the javascript code for e-commerce tracking in a script tag in the HTML which I then insert via AJAX without first having to initiate google analytics again? So I would have something like this:

HTML inserted via ajax:

```
<h2>Thanks for ordering.</h2>
<script>
ga('require', 'ecommerce');
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id': '1',
    'revenue': '100',
    'shipping': '1'
});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id': '1',
    'name': 'Test item name',
    'sku': 'ABC123',
    'category': 'test category',
    'price': '100',
    'quantity': '1'
});
ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

Would this track correctly? And if a visitor quickly closes the page or navigates away there's probably the possibility that the javascript isn't executed?

Any more hints on how I should tackle this issue are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Create ecommerce code in ajax script and send pageview in originating page.

It works but maybe something wrong with this and I just don't notice it. :)

Overall it will look like this:

---

generate_ecommerce_data.php:

```
<?
//logic to create following data
ga('ec:addProduct', {
  'id': '{$product['sku_id']}',
  'name': '{$product['title']}',
  'brand': '{$product['brand']}',
  'category': '{$product['category']}',
  'price': '$price',
  'quantity': $quantity
});

ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
  'id': '$transaction_code',
  'affiliation': 'NameName',
  'revenue': '$total_sum',
  'shipping': '$delivery_cost'
});
```

On calling page:

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-UANUMBER', 'NameName');
    ga('require', 'ec');

$('#element').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ajax/generate_ecommerce_data.php',
        success: function(response) {
            $('#container').html('<script>' + response + '<\/script>');
            ga('send', 'pageview'); 
            $('#container').html('');
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err.status);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

P.S.:
Looks like I exceeded message limit and needed to trim ajax code but you can get the idea.